# How to make one div tag next to the other div tag

Tags: html, css

[image]

My CSS File goes like this

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


#test
{   background:#0CF;
    text-align:right;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:735px;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:inherit;

    }

    #text
{
    background:#C6C;
    text-align:left;
    margin-right:203px;
    margin-top:-18px;
    }

        .main
{   background:#396
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:150px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:40px;
    position:fixed;
     border: 1px solid;
    }

.container
{

    background:#CCC;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-right:20px;
    width:299px;
    height:270px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top:-74px;

    bottom:100px;
    right:5px;

    }
```

This is the HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="prat.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="main">
<div id="text">
  <p>Thankyou for taking the time to visit our website.

This site exists primarily for existing clients to access updates on current investments they have with us and for Marketwise Investments to provide new opportunities as they arise.

If you are a prospective client, please read on to learn more about MarketWise Investments and the work we do.

MarketWise Investments is a Sydney-based development and property investment company with a diverse range of projects across Australia and overseas.
</p>
</div>
<div id="test">
<p>We offer professional, efficient investment.and development strategies for clients in both domestic and international markets, looking for cash-positive property investments where possible.</p>
</div>
<span class="container">
<p>We offer professional, efficient investment and development strategies for clients in both domestic and international markets, looking for cash-positive property investments where possible.

All projects are carefully considered and aligned with market demand to maximize the best possible returns for our clients.</p>
</span>
</div>


cross browser 
grade
box model

</body>
</html>
```

In the picture you can see one div tag is not next to the other one. I want to put it in top. I tried margin with -. But didnt work out. Can someone help me

Comment: You should only tag your CSS questions with `css3` if you're happy to receive answers that only work in modern browsers and (often) not widely used but crap browsers such as IE8.

Answer (score 2):

use `float:left` on both `div`'s

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this css3, Ill give you the css3 answer.

```
<body>
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
  <div id="box3">3</div>
</body>
```

(Use vendor prefixes)

```
body{
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
}
```

See http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

Also http://jsfiddle.net/4eqve/

Comment: i think im doing in different version of CSS. but i was searching about Box model. so thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
#box1 {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100px;
    background:#0CF; 
    }

#box2 {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background:#C6C;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<section id="box_wrap">
  <div id="box1">1</div>
  <div id="box2">2</div>
</section>
```

**Result:** http://jsfiddle.net/j3ffz/pDjEj/

Comment: This breaks when using some elements with padding/margin.